# jupyter notebook ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings

Tags: python, jupyter, mediapipe

when i use jupyter notebook import mediapipe .I meet a problem ,it is No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings',but import other model is ok .And use pycharm import mediapipe also ok .

my pip list has mediapipe ,but import mediapipe still has  No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, Just restarting the Kernel helped: Kernel -> Restart

Comment: Please put this as a comment, not the answer.